# Multiple "Sprites" in one VBO

Tags: opengl

From what I understand the VBO is memory on the GPU where we can send Vertices, and the VAO is where you can store different VBO's which you can then bind to draw those vertexes.

If I rendered a cube with one VBO and I wanted to render another shape at the same time such as a pyramid, would I create a VBO for each "object" or would I just send in new vertex positions.

I understand how to draw a simple cube or multiple, but I don't understand drawing multiple different shapes at the same time

Comment: "*at the same time*" What do you mean by that? You only have 1 GPU, and it can only do one thing at a time. So either the other shape is rendered before the cube or after it. It could be before/after it in the same rendering command (in which case, you're not "rendering a cube"; you're just drawing triangles that happen to *form* a cube), but you're not rendering them "at the same time".

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity,  I mean in simple terms would it be better to use 1 x VBO for all my objects on the screen in a game or should I just have a VBO for each "object/sprite"?

Comment: Simple answer: have only one VBO with all the "objects/sprites" inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple objects in one VBO . You could use [Instancing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing). Then you may create 3 vec4 attribute locations in your vbo and use that to construct a mat4 object[the last row would be 0,0,0,1] in your shader for your transformations.

The above approach will work if your whole mesh consists of only triangles or any other primitive of a single type but if you have different topologies mixed in your VBO say A cube which you draw using Indexed Triangles and then a circle which you would draw using Triangle fans or something similar then you would use [glDrawElementsBaseVertex](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glDrawElementsBaseVertex.xhtml) where the base vertex is the starting vertex of your primitive in the vbo.

If each of these  different primitives had their own instance attributes say you wanted to draw 2 green color cubes and then 3 red color circles in that order [where color is an per instance attribute so there are totally 5 colors in all] Then you would use [glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance.xhtml) where you can specify from what instance [or in this case from what color you want start rendering from]

It depends on your use case. If I need to modify the vertex information of large meshes then storing loads of them in one VBO can be a problem as I have to keep track of the offsets  into the vbo where each mesh starts and it becomes even harder after you interleave your attributes.

But for drawing sprites or multiple instances of one mesh type where you don't often modify the vertex data in your VBO then storing all your data in one VBO is an good way to go.